# Firefox request repetition on slow inet connection

Tags: firefox, request, pooling, repeat

i tried to search on mozillas buglist but that was not really successful, thats why im asking you guys.

Do you ever heard that firefox is repeating the request when the server response takes to long or the user connection is to slow?

In my case the user submits the form and waits for the response, for any reason that takes up to 1 minute and in that time-frame the server receives more or less 5 times the request.

Any idea? I appreciate your help, hope for solutions :S

Take care